# Jump to next searchable text.

Tags: hyperlink, navigation, automation

I contribute to develop a wrapper for a bioinformatics program. 
The program's output is quite long (dozens of pages if printed), but structured into sections.

I would like to add "next" and "previous" section buttons to facilitate jumping up and down in the output.

One way of doing this would involve parsing the complete output, adding "id" or "name" anchors and linking to neighboring sections using `<a href="#section2">` type links. However, thats a pain in the butt to do, adds the potential of new bugs, and would slow down the display.

All sections start "in the same manner" (ie. if you control-F search for a specific text, you will jump to the next section). Is there an easy way of using the fact that all sections start with the same text to add links that will let you jump to the next one?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the jQuery [ScrollTo plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) can help you. You could add the links you need for navigating by Javascript/jQuery after the page has loaded.